# Saving entire model as TF SavedModel using Callback in TF 1.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to save my entire model every couple of epochs, including state of the optimizer, custom metrics etc. during training with keras `model.fit_generator()`. The goal is to be able to resume training from the exact state where it was left off.

The code I am working with is in TF 1.14. I know about the ModelCheckpoint callback, but it saves models in hdf5 format by default, which apparently can't deal properly with custom loss. I thought that probably the callback is just calling `model.save()` in the predefined interval during training, so is there a way to change file format passed to this call to SavedModel in versions earlier than TF 2.x, yielding my desired result?

Answer (score 1):

This code was tested with TF 1.15

```py
import numpy as np
import keras
```

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_pred*y_pred - y_true*y_true


m = keras.models.Sequential()
m.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=(10,)))
m.compile('adam', loss=custom_loss)
```

```py
x = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(200,10))
y = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(200,3))
```

```py
mc = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('F:\\model.h5')
m.fit(x,y,callbacks=[mc])
```

```
Epoch 1/1
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 70us/step - loss: -622.8262
```

```py
m = keras.models.load_model('F:\\model.h5', custom_objects={'custom_loss': custom_loss})
```

```py
m.fit(x,y)
```

```
Epoch 1/1
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 244us/step - loss: -800.1645
```

Comment: I had tried that before

It results in the following error with TF1.14:
'File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 211, in deserialize_keras_object
    raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ':' + object_name)
ValueError: Unknown loss function:n2v_mse'